# Connection Timed Out Error during setup keys installation

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there! I am new to ROS, and I need a little help here
with installing ROS on my Ubuntu. I am running Ubuntu as a virtual
OS in Windows 7 using VMware Player. Here are some details regarding
the software.

**Ubuntu version:** Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) 32-bit

**ROS version:** ROS fuerte

So I followed the step by step procedure for installing fuerte as given here

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

But when I try to install step number 3 (setup your keys), the connection fails
and I get a "Connection timed out. Could not connect to packages.ros.org" error.
And then it keeps on trying to connect (which may be because of wget command) but
always fails. I am using an Ethernet LAN cable connection for the internet, and the weird part is
that I am connected to the net all the while that I am getting this error. I then
tried the following, which again is never able to complete (Gets stuck at 0%)

sudo apt-get install update

What may possibly be wrong here? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Nishant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34613/connection-timed-out-error-during-setup-keys-installation/) by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 143 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nishant](https://answers.ros.org/users/2440/nishant/) on 2012-05-22**:
I am so sorry for the small mistake in the post above. What I tried out was

sudo apt-get update

This still didn't work though. The computer hangs up on 0%, until I have to kill the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like a network connectivity issue. You should check that you can reach packages.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0